# Cassandra : How to get the String value of column data irrespective of datatype

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to fetch the results from a `com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet` and print it:

```
ResultSet results = getSession().execute("Select * from test.table"); //getsession returns a session
int numcols = results.getColumnDefinitions().size();
for ( Row row : results ) {
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numcols; colIndex++) {
           System.out.println("data: " + row.getString(colIndex));
     }
}
```

`row.getString(colIndex)` throws an exception in case of datatypes other than String. How will I be able to get a string data irrespective of what data type it is?

Comment: Is there a metadata retrieval call that can return the column types? If not you may be out of luck, but if there is you can write code to handle all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will print the type of each column and value

```
ResultSet results = getSession().execute("Select * from test.table");    
int numcols = results.getColumnDefinitions().size();
for ( Row row : results ) {
   for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numcols; colIndex++) {
         System.out.println("Type : "+row.getColumnDefinitions().getType(colIndex));
         Class c = row.getColumnDefinitions().getType(colIndex).asJavaClass();
         if(c == Integer.class) {
              System.out.println("Data :" + row.getInt(colIndex));
         }
         //similar for other type
   }
}
```